# Sine and Cosine

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, trigonometry

Can someone explain how sin(e)&cos(ine) can be used to get the end projection coordinates(x,y) of a rotating object?
Ive tried in some many different ways but english is not my native language. Makes it rather hard for me to understand.

Comment: You realize there's a SE site for math right? http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why would people think that this belongs on programmers...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sinus and cosinus can be used to calculate the sides in a right triangle:

```
       B
      /|
     / |
    /  |
   /   |
  /    |
 /\a   |
A__\___C
```

From the length of the side A-B and the angle a, you can calculate the sides A-C and B-C:

```
A-C = A-B * cos a
B-C = A-B * sin a
```

If you place A at the center of a circle and move the point B around the edge, you can calculate the coordinates of B from the angle and the radius.

```
x = r * cos a
y = r * sin a

       y
       ^
     . | .
   .   +   B
 .     |     .
.      |      .
.      A---+---> x
.             .
 .           .
   .       .
     . . .
```

For angles from 0 to 90 degrees it's a simple triangle, but when you get over 90 degrees the cosinus value gets negative, which means that the x coordinate is to the left of the center. Over 180 degrees sinus gets negative, which means that y is below the center. Over 270 degrees cosinus gets positive again, so it's to the right of the center, bringing us around to 360 degrees where sinus gets positive again.